# Бесконечный цикл WHILE c urllib.request.urlopen("адрес") глохнет спустя 2-3 часа

Tags: python, python-3.x, while, raspberry-pi

Сделал простой скрипт, который стартует при запуске PI. Состоит из бесконечного цикла, который отправляет параметры на сервер.

Проблема в том, что спустя часа 2-3 все глохнет, хотя малинка не зависла, и демон вроде даже как висит в памяти.

В чем может быть проблема?

```
while 1:
    doc = urllib.request.urlopen("адрес")
    time.sleep(600)
```

Использую *raspberryPi 3*.

Comment: Раскройте ваши понятия:  "все глохнет" и "демон вроде даже как висит"  - более детально.

Comment: Бесконечный цикл вроде бы пишется через `True`? `while True: pass`

Comment: У вас просто неправильно сделан логгинг и обработка ошибок

Comment: разницы нет, все будет приведено к bool.

Comment: `urllib.request.urlopen("адрес", timeout=30)` а потом видно будет

Comment: @0xdb я сижу грубо говоря "на другом конце" и просматриваю данные которые мне присылает Pi, даже если меня нет, там фиксируется время последнего обращения. Так вот спустя 2-3 часа данные с малины перестают приходить, малина не зависает ибо к ней всё так же можно подключиться по удаленке, а при просмотре процессов видно и этот скрипт, тоесть он не крашнулся.

Comment: @andreymal с таймаутом проработала 3 часа 50 минут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением стала обработка ошибок

```python
import time, requests 

while True: 
        try: 
             requests.get('адрес', timeout=(10)) 
        except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout: 
             print('Oops. Read timeout occured') 
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: 
             print('Oops. Connection timeout occured!') 
        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err: 
             print('Oops. HTTP Error occured') 
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
             print('Oops. Connection error!') 
        time.sleep(60)
```